# Exporting Users base on projects

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, project, multiple-users

Is there a way to export users based on project/teams?  I need to create another team within another project but somehow I'm not able to add another project group to a different project

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a straight forward way to do that. As a work around, you could use DevOps REST API to achieve this.

I am using DevOps PAT for Basic Auth.

Use this API to get userID in your DevOps organization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/get-user-entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

GET [https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=5.1-preview.2](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=5.1-preview.2)

[image]

Create a new Team in another and use this API to get groupID for this Team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

GET [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

[image]

With the userID and groupID collected, you could use this API to add members into this team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

PUT [https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/{groupId}/members/{memberId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/GroupEntitlements/%7BgroupId%7D/members/%7BmemberId%7D?api-version=5.1-preview.1)

[image]